# Multistep form - strange behaviour with field filled by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with script who filled `input` field when one value is less than 4. When the value is less than 4 the script filling field but the value is not `selected`, so when I'm going to next step I have no value in this field. When the value is greater than 4 everything is ok (the value is also filling by jquery).

This is my code:

```
function compute() {
      if( parseInt($("#finish_day").val()) < 4 ) {  
            $('#return_car').children('#return_car option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']').attr('selected', true).siblings().attr('disabled', true);

            if ($('#return_car').val()) $('#return_car').change();
        }
        else {
            $('#get_car > option, #return_car > option').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#three_day').hide(2000, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

    }
$('select#get_car').change(compute);
$('input#finish_day').change(compute);
```

HTML code:

```
<form>    
<fieldset>    
<div class="type-select">   
    <label for="get_car">Miasto wynajmu: *</label>
    <select id="get_car" name="rent-a-car-next[get_car]" class="select">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="Katowice">Katowice</option>
        <option value="Kraków">Kraków</option>
        <option value="Warszawa">Warszawa</option>
        <option value="Wrocław">Wrocław</option>
        <option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk</option>
    </select>   
</div>

<div class="type-select">   
    <label for="return_car">Miasto zwrotu: </label>
    <select id="return_car" name="rent-a-car-next[return_car]" class="select">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="Katowice">Katowice</option>
        <option value="Kraków">Kraków</option>
        <option value="Warszawa">Warszawa</option>
        <option value="Wrocław">Wrocław</option>
        <option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk</option>
    </select>   
</div>

<div class="type-text">
  <label for="finish_day">Ilość dni wynajmu: </label>
  <input type="text" size="20" id="finish_day" name="rent-a-car-next[finish_day]" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div class="type-button">
  <input type="submit" name="rent-a-car-next[step-2-next]" class="button submit" value="Kolejny krok" />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Where is the problem? Thanks for any help

Comment: Would be better to create a fiddle to showcase your issue.

Comment: ok, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/W7NHK/66/

Comment: Try removing `"#return_car"` from the start of the selector passed to `.children()`. And note that not all browsers support disabling individual options within a select element.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change - still the same problem

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the problem, but it seemed to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/W7NHK/67/ (Though your demo doesn't include the next step, so...)

Comment: but how to insert the next step to jsfiddle... The code works fine but the value who is inserted to `#return_car` don't have the `selected` attribute. When user select this field or the value of #finish_day` is greater than `4` everything is ok.

Comment: Maybe the `function compute()` is the reason? I also try to rewrite this part of code to `.change(function()` but I don't have enough knowledge and the code didn't work.. http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/W7NHK/72/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved:

```
$('#return_car').children('option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']').prop('disabled', false).attr('selected', true).siblings().prop('disabled', true);
```

Regards